# how to get images from other frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsbundle, nscursor

I would like to have a my cursor with the same shape as in Lion

So Instead of having this:
[image: NSCursor icon]

I would like to have this:[image: NSCursor in Lion]

Which can be found at:
`System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors/resizeeastwest/cursor.png` in the new OSX 10.7 GM

Is there a way I can load that image using methods from NSBundle or so? I would like to have not the same image into my application (as a resource) if I can use the image from the system.

Comment: I would not recommend reaching into the bundle like that.  If there is no public API for getting that image, you open yourself up to problems should Apple decide to move/remove the file at that bundle path.  As much as you do not want to add it to your application bundle proper, it insulates you from a change over which you do not have control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up by copying the resources into my project and access them the usual way

```
NSImage *cursorImg = [NSImage imageNamed:@"cursor.png"];
```

This seem to be the safest way.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors/resizeeastwest/cursor.png"];
```